# Anyone has idea how to beautify windows terminal like this

Tags: windows-terminal

Anyone has idea how to beautify windows terminal like this? same background, same color combination :)

[image]

Comment: I think this is a app from Microsoft store, search terminal

Comment: Right. I have app but to beautify it like image shown.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Steps on how to customize Windows Terminal -
**Github Link** - https://github.com/anup-a/Beautify-your-Windows-Terminal

**Link to the dev.to article** - https://dev.to/anupa/beautify-your-windows-terminal-1la8

Answer (score 1):

That is Powerline for Powershell. You can go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/powerline-setup) for help setting that up.

The background is transparent and acryllic which you can turn on in your Powershell profile in settings.json by setting `"useAcrylic": true` and `"acrylicOpacity": 0.4`  which would look something like this:

```
{
  // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile.
  "guid": "{YOUR GUID HERE}",
  "name": "Windows PowerShell",
  "commandline": "powershell.exe",
  "useAcrylic": true,
  "acrylicOpacity": 0.4,
  "hidden": false
},
```

If you are on Windows, make sure you have 'Transparency effects' turned on in `Personalize-->Colors`